# pandasdmx unable to create DataFrame for some OECD data

Tags: python, json, api, pandas

I’m using pandasdmx version 0.7.0, and though I’m having success with OECD data sets with a Frequency dimension, there are other data sets like the Fossil Fuel Supports data sets, which have no Frequency dimension where I’m unable to create a pandas DataFrame, like below:

```
from pandasdmx import Request

# http://stats.oecd.org/sdmx-json/data/FFS_BRA/all/all

oecd = Request('OECD')

try:
    data_response = oecd.data(resource_id='FFS_BRA', key='all/all')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    pass
except KeyError:
    pass
else:
    oecd_data = data_response.data

    print(oecd_data.dim_at_obs)
    series_list = list(oecd_data.series)
    print(len(series_list))
    print(series_list[0].key)
    print(set(s.key.FUEL for s in oecd_data.series))

    fuel = (s for s in oecd_data.series if s.key.FUEL == 'HARDCOAL')
    df = data_response.write(fuel)

print("completed ...")

Output:

TIME_PERIOD
25
SeriesKeyTuple(MEA='BRA_DT_03', FUEL='HARDCOAL',  IND='CSE',INC='CONSUMPTION', STG='GENER', MEC='DT', LVL='FED')
{'NONBIOJETK', 'LIGNITE', 'HARDCOAL', 'NAPHTHA', 'NONBIODIES', 'CRUDEOIL', 'RESFUEL', 'NATGAS', 'NGL', 'LPG', 'NONBIOGASO'}

File "stackoverflow_dataframe.py", line 23, in <module>
df = data_response.write(fuel)
File "pandasdmx\api.py", line 635, in write
return self._writer.write(source=source, **kwargs)
File "pandasdmx\writer\data2pandas.py", line 109, in write
reverse_obs, fromfreq, parse_time))
File "pandasdmx\writer\data2pandas.py", line 107, in <genexpr>
series_list = list(s for s in self.iter_pd_series(
File "pandasdmx\writer\data2pandas.py", line 228, in iter_pd_series
obs_values, index=series_index, name=series.key)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'series_index' referenced before assignment
```

Is this the right approach for non-frequency dimension data sets, or have I just coded it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The offical answer from the author of pandasdmx (0.7.0) is to use the parse_time parameter set to False for the write function. The write function then does not attempt to generate a DateTime index, and instead you get a string index.

```
from pandasdmx import Request

# http://stats.oecd.org/sdmx-json/data/FFS_BRA/all/all

oecd = Request('OECD')

try:
    data_response = oecd.data(resource_id='FFS_BRA', key='all/all')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
     pass
except KeyError:
    pass
else:
    oecd_data = data_response.data

    df = data_response.write(oecd_data.series, parse_time=False)
    df.to_csv('FFS_BRA_solution1.csv')
```

As pandasdmx returns a wide format table using SDMX IDs for column names and data, and due to time pressure, I wrote my own to return a long format table (which I could then pivot if required), with the option of using SDMX IDs or full descriptions. This solution has been tested on 835 OECD data sets!

```
from pandasdmx import Request
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

# http://stats.oecd.org/sdmx-json/data/FFS_BRA/all/all

# generator of empty lists
def create(n, constructor=list):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield constructor()

# note this function extracts annual data
# DataFrame in long format
def createDF(sdmx_data, useIDs=False):

    series_list = list(sdmx_data.series)

    # does it have a frequency dimension?
    # if only use the annual data
    keycheck_tuple = series_list[0].key._fields
    for keycheck in keycheck_tuple:
        if keycheck == 'FREQUENCY':
            series_list = (anl for anl in sdmx_data.series if anl.key.FREQUENCY == 'A')
            break
        elif keycheck == 'FREQ':
            series_list = (anl for anl in sdmx_data.series if anl.key.FREQ == 'A')
            break

    # variable series key columns for the data set
    # list of empty lists
    key_columns = list(create(sdmx_data._reader._key_len))

    # fixed columns for time period and values
    time_period_col = []
    value_col = []

    for s in series_list:
        s_key_tuple = s.key
        s_elem_dict = s._elem
        s_reader = s._reader

        obs_dim_dict = s_reader._obs_dim[0]['values']

        total_keys = s_reader._key_len
        key_col_codes = []

        for key in range(total_keys):
            keys_list = s_reader._series_dim[key]['values']
            key_field_abbrev = s_key_tuple._fields[key]
            key_code = s_key_tuple[key_field_abbrev]
            if useIDs:
                key_col_codes.append(key_code)
            else:
                for entry_dict in keys_list:
                    if entry_dict['id'] == key_code:
                        key_col_codes.append(entry_dict['name'])

        obs_dict = s_elem_dict['observations']
        for key, val_list in sorted(obs_dict.items()):
            value_col.append(val_list[0])
            yr = obs_dim_dict[int(key)]['name']
            time_period_col.append(yr)
            for ky in range(sdmx_data._reader._key_len):
                key_columns[ky].append(key_col_codes[ky])

    pandasdict = OrderedDict()

    tp = 'Time Period'
    ob = 'Observation'
    if useIDs:
        tp = 'TIME_PERIOD'
        ob = 'OBS'

    pandasdict[tp] = time_period_col
    pandasdict[ob] = value_col

    for t in range(sdmx_data._reader._key_len):
        if useIDs:
            # use this for abbreviated column names
            pandasdict[s_key_tuple._fields[t]] = key_columns[t]
        else:
            # use this for un-abbreviated column names
            pandasdict[s_reader._series_dim[t]['name']] = key_columns[t]

    oecdDF = pd.DataFrame(pandasdict)

    return oecdDF


# OECD data
oecd = Request('OECD')

try:
    data_response = oecd.data(resource_id='FFS_BRA', key='all/all')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    pass
except KeyError:
    pass
else:
    oecd_data = data_response.data

    # long format
    df = createDF(oecd_data, useIDs=False)
    df.to_csv('FFS_BRA_solution2_long.csv')

    # wide format
    all_cols_list = df.columns.values.tolist()
    pivot = df.pivot_table(values=all_cols_list[1], index=all_cols_list[0], columns=all_cols_list[2:])
    pivot.to_csv('FFS_BRA_solution2_wide.csv')
```